# Max size Google sheet, with apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have just a little question about my spreadsheet's power. Because I made a huge sheet file with many calculations and many function apps script (I have 7 500 rows and 7 function in apps script). So I would like to know if there exists a limit size for the sheet files, and if it exists, is my file too large?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this page (the numbers are increasing in time): https://gsuitetips.com/tips/sheets/google-spreadsheet-limitations/
https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603?hl=en

### Google Spreadsheets are extremely powerful and convert very well from Excel, but they do have some limitations:

- Up to 5 million cells for spreadsheets that are created in or converted to Google Sheets
- 40,000 new rows at a time
- Maximum number of columns of 18,278 columns
- Number of Tabs: 200 sheets per workbook
- GoogleFinance formulas: 1,000 GoogleFinance formulas
- ImportRange formulas: 50 cross-workbook reference formulas
- ImportData, ImportHtml, ImportFeed, or ImportXml formulas: 50 functions for external data
- Maximum string length is 50,000 characters

### Quotas for the  Apps Script:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations

- Script runtime: 6 min/execution
- Custom function runtime: 30 sec/execution
- Simultaneous executions: 30

Comment: Ok thanks you very much for the info, do you know if i can see some slow-down before this limit, because me sheet file is already very slow, and everytime when i update a new fonction in a cell, the file take to much time to update himself

Comment: @JosephMenard You're right. Google sheets have the advantage of accessibility from anywhere, the possibility of cooperation, and it is quite a powerful office tool (graphs, tables for presentations, documents). Trying to take full advantage of the above limits is not a good way to go. Sometimes I work with spreadsheets from my mobile phone, and there it is noticeable.  
If you need to handle big data analytics and don't want to give up the benefits of Google, you can try [tag:google-bigquery]. Another option is to switch from the Cloud to your PC. Use appropriate tools.